# Can I access and query web-based Crystal Report Viewer through Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vbscript, crystal-reports, vba

I download reports through web-based access to a Crystal Report Viewer. (Admittedly, my first problem is that I am not at all proficient with Crystal.) I generally have success using Excel VBA in automating IE navigation and HTML form manipulation, but I've run into a wall with this Crystal Report Viewer.

As an example, I can download a report through the Crystal Report Viewer by specifying for which of the fifty states I want the report. I am trying to automate it so that it will export all fifty reports at once (or, rather, in succession while I, say, go to lunch).

I've pulled the outerHTML of the site in question. It includes an OBJECT tag at the beginning containing 23 PARAM NAME tags followed by the following VBScript:

```
Sub window_onLoad()
  Page_Initialize()
End Sub
Sub Page_Initialize
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim webBroker
  Set webBroker = CreateObject("WebReportBroker.WebReportBroker")
  If err.number <> 0 then
    window.alert "The Crystal ActiveX Viewer is unable to create resource objects."
    CRViewer.ReportName = "[a URL...redacted]"
  Else
    Dim webSource0
    Set webSource0 = CreateObject("WebReportSource.WebReportSource")
    webSource0.ReportSource = webBroker
    webSource0.URL = "[a URL...redacted]"
    webSource0.PromptOnRefresh = True
    webSource0.AddParameter "password", "[somepassword]"
    webSource0.AddParameter "user", "[someuser]"
    CRViewer.ReportSource = webSource0
  End if
  CRViewer.ViewReport
End Sub
```

This script was followed by three more OBJECT tags, each making reference to codebases. I navigated to these references to find DLLs, which I would assume indicate the references I need to invoke in my VBA. On a hunch, I moved the VBScript into Excel VBA (is this dumb?) and placed it after my usual login and navigating code. I get a "Compile Error: Variable not defined" on the lines

```
window.alert "The Crystal ActiveX Viewer..." 'highlighting the word "window"

CRViewer.ReportName = "[a URL...redacted]"   'highlighting "CRViewer"

CRViewer.ReportSource = webSource0           'highlighting "CRViewer"

CRViewer.ViewReport                          'highlighting "CRViewer"
```

This is where I run into problems. First, I may be going about this the wrong way, or it may not even be possible; but I wouldn't know. Second, if I am on the right track, there are A LOT of Crystal references listed in Excel VBA's available references. I have no idea which ones to use. BTW: the codebases make reference to

- crviewer.dll
- sviewhlp.dll
- swebrs.dll
- xqviewer.dll
- cselexpt.ocx
- crviewer.dep
- crviewer.oca and
- reportparameterdialog.dll

Any help would be appreciated. I realize I may not have provided all the necessary information here. Please let me know if more is needed. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Web viewer part of a wider Business Objects setup, or something more basic that simply launches a viewer with the report?

If it's the former, you already have easier options for automating distribution via the web-based CMC, wherein report refreshes can be scheduled with a variety of distribution options, including to UNC paths.

If its the later, or for some reason the standard CMC/BO options aren't suitable, you might consider using a code library made for this purpose. The splinter library for Python is one such, and my preferred package for web automation: http://splinter.cobrateam.info/

If VBA is your coding comfort zone, there are a few ways of integrating python into VBA, all merely a google away... I won't detail them here since that's a sideline to this, and my answer is more of an alternative than a direct answer.